# How to adjust buttons properly inside LinearLayout if text on first button is more then half of screen

Tags: android, view, android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout, android-xml

I am working on a layout file which have one parent LinearLayout and inside it two buttons and goal is to adjust buttons alignment according to the text size of buttons for an example if text size of any of button increase to half of the screen buttons should position them vertically otherwise should be show horizontally. Need help to fix this issue. Below is the layout file and its output that is tried so far.

**xml:**

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingVertical="0dp"
            android:text="I am long text to feed this button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="Test" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Expected behaviour:**

Scenario 1: If text size of any button is greater then half of screen.

[image]

Scenario 2: If text size is less then half of screen.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at using [FlexboxLayout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) or [ConstraintLayout Flow](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/helper/widget/Flow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution so posting here too. Thanks @Cheticamp it works with `androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow` in `ConstraintLayout`

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
....Other Views...

<Button
    android:id="@+id/primary_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/secondary_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
    android:id="@+id/flow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:constraint_referenced_ids="primary_button,secondary_button"
    app:flow_horizontalBias="0"
    app:flow_horizontalStyle="packed"
    app:flow_horizontalGap="5dp"
    app:flow_verticalBias="0"
    app:flow_wrapMode="chain"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textview" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```